# How to get oozie workflow duration at the end

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

Is there any way to email the duration of the workflow with the completion email?  Is there such a variable that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think such a variable is available. But if needed you can do such using shell action. During your workflow start execute a shell script for start time and save it in a variable. At the time of workflow just finish before your email action have a another shell script which will calculate the current time - start time and use it in your email. But this makes your workflow dirty

Comment: I thought about this, but was hoping for a cleaner solution.  Interestingly enough, Hue interface is able to show the duration; thus, I'm assuming it should be somewhere in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a remarkable shortcoming of Oozie.  Each of our workflows starts with an shell action that calls a simple bash script to get timestamp.

```
<action name="start-time">
  <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <exec>utc-time.sh</exec>
    <file>../common/utc-time.sh#utc-time.sh</file>
    <capture-output/>
  </shell>
  <ok to="the-first-actual-action"/>
  <error to="fail"/>
</action>
```

And this is testable with Java EL in the email we send on completion, error, like so:

```
<action name="email">
  <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
    <to>${emailsToAlert}</to>
    <subject>COMPLETED: ${wf:name()}</subject>
    <body>
      Workflow ID: ${wf:id()}
      Workflow Name: ${wf:name()}
      Workflow app path: ${wf:appPath()}
      Start Time: ${wf:actionData('start-time')['time']}
      End Time: ${timestamp()}
    </body>
  </email>
  <ok to="end"/>
  <error to="fail"/>
</action>
```

Getting duration is another jump-through-hoop exercise involving passing the start and end time to a bash script.

I was investigating the [Oozie SLA functionality](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/DG_SLAMonitoring.html), but I haven't found a way to extract the data.